# Pointer Snaps to Bottom of Screen when using Touchpad

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch, cursor, xinput

So I've been looking at some of the other questions asked here regarding cursors jumping when the touchpad is clicked and it doesn't seem that I'm having the same issue as them. I believe my issue has something to do with multi-touch when the left-button is clicked or held-down.

There are two instances in which I'm having the issue with my pointer, when clicking right after having moved the cursor, and when holding down on the left-button and moving the cursor (such as to drag a window). I will suddenly have the cursor snap into the bottom-left of my screen. I have also noticed, what I believe, to be the set of 4 events that are causing the issue from evtest.

When clicking after moving I get this:

```
Event: time 1457106182.202264, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 58 (ABS_MT_PRESSURE), value 39
Event: time 1457106182.202264, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 39
Event: time 1457106182.202264, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457106182.212447, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1457106182.212447, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1457106182.212447, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 0
Event: time 1457106182.212447, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 0
Event: time 1457106182.212447, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

When holding the left-button and dragging:

```
Event: time 1457107443.726386, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 2353
Event: time 1457107443.726386, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 4351
Event: time 1457107443.726386, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 58 (ABS_MT_PRESSURE), value 54
Event: time 1457107443.726386, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 2353
Event: time 1457107443.726386, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 4351
Event: time 1457107443.726386, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 54
Event: time 1457107443.726386, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1457107443.735923, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1457107443.735923, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1457107443.735923, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 0
Event: time 1457107443.735923, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 0
Event: time 1457107443.735923, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

That specific sequence of 4 events seems to occur every time the cursor snaps to the bottom-left of the screen every time it happens. So is that something that I'd be able to filter out? Or is there some setting to prevent this from happening?